# Azure B2C Active Directory Custom login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have our own login page to authenticate users against the Azure B2C directory. What is the right approach to achieve it.
I am not sure if this custom validation would also require policies to be created. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "own login page"? You have to use the B2C one.

Comment: If you are talking about look and feel, yes, that's easy. But it has to contain the B2C login elements. You can't design your own from scratch and authenticate via an API. That's why I asked the above question.

Comment: @nzpcmad ok. So i cannot authenticate using my own APIs. So i have to basically use B2C authenticatin with UX customization.

Comment: Yup. No Microsoft identity products have API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have designed a custom login page, you need to implement it through UI customization in Azure Active Directory B2C.

Generally speaking, you need to use [Custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview#custom-policies) to make it completely.

Besides, [client-side JavaScript code in User Flow or Custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview#javascript) can be used to design the UI. You can see if it meets your needs.

See more options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview#ui-customization-in-different-scenarios).